# Liferay control the portlet arrangement when the layout changes

Tags: liferay

I am using responsive design in my application, and want to know if the portlets placed in the page can be rearranged when the browser resolution changes.

Say, suppose i have two portlets in my page.One placed on  the left side and the other at right side.Now what i want is to show the right portlet on the top of the page when the browser width/resolution is changed or it is viewed in mobiles.

Currently the left portlet is shown on the top of the page when the width/ resolution is changed or it is viewed in mobile.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this blog post](http://www.liferay.com/it/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/liferay-com-mobile-sites-and-responsive-layouts): it basically shows how to use the AUI Viewport component, which automatically adds CSS classes to the `<html>` tag depending on the width of your window.

You can also have a look at the [Spain Symposium 2012 website](http://www.liferay.com/web/spain2012) (and [this](http://www.liferay.com/it/web/ronald.sarayudej/blog/-/blogs/making-a-website-responsive-in-about-one-week)), which is a nice example of responsive design in Liferay, made by Liferay itself.